# How can i play a video in full screen in another activity on clicking a card view

Tags: android, android-studio, video, web-applications, view

Can you guys please answer completely..i read an answer to the same question but they used putExtra method..i don't know where it is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you have asked involves a larger implementation with code.

1. Use ExoPlayer to play videos in android. You can learn it from this [CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0) and also check this for more [information](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer).
2. From your question i understand there is a cardView and when you press it, a video show play in another activity. So for this you need to know how to use [Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) in android. Intents help in passing data(such as a video url) from one activity to another.
3. Also check this [project](https://github.com/RajashekarRaju/BakingApp) which uses ExoPlayer to play videos from internet with URL.

Comment: I have opt for 2nd option. Can you please tell me how to play videos according to card selected and also i want to play all video in single activity so that i dont have to make different activities for all cards..hope you understood and can help asap

Comment: Yes in second point you will learn passing data from one activity to another. Now think you have passed data which is url of video of type string to play in another activity. Now Learn implementing the ExoPlayer which information i have addd in first point.

Comment: Can't I play video without using exoPlayer, I have added activities

Comment: Activities won't help you play video's. Android uses different types of API's to implement features. Speaking in this case ExoPlayer is an API which helps to play video and audio in android. Activity is something which holds all the information we are adding to the app, you can pretty much imagine it as an empty CANVAS.